Unstaged files that were accidentally uploaded to GitHub before there was a gitignore file
My friends and I are working on a project in github but by mistake changes were pushed to master before a gitignore file was uploaded that indicates to ignore these files
And when someone wants to merge or push changes, many files are shown to him as unstaged
Except for the files he changed (these are files created for example in bin folders, cache files and more). We tried uploading a gitignore file but still can't get rid of these files.
Tried reuploading gitignore file, clearing git cache but to no avail

git push -f can replace the history, but you need to decide how you are going to re-create old commits. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Does this answer your question? How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?

Ideally, you should rewrite the history such that the files are never present. Then everyone should resume their work on the rewritten history.
